# Converting string to date returns nil for a particular date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I came across a strange issue. When I am converting "1942-09-01 00:00:00.0" to nsdate, it's not converting. But there is no issue with other dates. I don't know the reason. Below is my code:

```
let dateString = "1942-09-01 00:00:00.0"
let dateformater = DateFormatter()
dateformater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0"
let dateFromString = dateformater.date(from: dateString)
print(dateFromString)
```

Comment: It is the same issue as in the linked-to "duplicate". On September 1, 1942, daylight saving time started at midnight and the clocks were adjusted one hour forward (assuming that you are in the Indian time zone). Therefore there is no "00:00:00" time on that day.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/india?year=1942